# How to pass a JavaScript int variable into ASP.NET MVC partial view?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In the following code, I am attempting to iterate over `geoMarkers` and create a Marker for each. The line of code here needs some help: 
   content: `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_MyPartialView.cshtml", Model.ElementAt(' + i + '))`

In this line above, I am attempting to pass the JavaScript variable `i` into a ASP.NET MVC call, which I know by searching isn't possible EXCEPT in cases where the JavaScript variable can be turned into a literal. In this case, I would like to turn the `i` into an int, but I'm struggling with the syntax. **How can I pass `i` into the `@Html.Partial` call?** Note that `_MyPartialView.cshtml` takes a `@model MyMarkerObject`.

Thank you!

```
@model List<MyMarkerObject>
@section scripts {
    <section class="scripts">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var geoMarkers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

            // Using the JQuery "each" selector to iterate through the JSON list and drop marker pins
            $.each(geoMarkers, function (i, item) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.GeoLatitude[0], item.GeoLongitude[0]),
                    map: map,
                    title: item.GeoFormattedAddress[0],
                });

                ///////////////// SET ICON TYPE ////////////////////////
                var thisIcon;
                if (item.Source.includes("parking")) {
                    thisIcon = icons.parking.icon;
                } else if (item.Source.includes("hotel")) {
                    thisIcon = icons.hotel.icon;
                } else if (item.Source.includes("restaurant")) {
                    thisIcon = icons.restaurant.icon;
                }

                // Use a different color depending on the source
                marker.setIcon(thisIcon);

                ///////////////// CREATE MAP EVENTS ////////////////////

                // put in some information about each json object - in this case, the opening hours.
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // HELP PLEASE HERE!
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    content: `@Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_MyPartialView.cshtml", Model.ElementAt(' + i + '))`
                });

                // finally hook up an "OnClick" listener to the map so it pops up out info-window when the marker-pin is clicked!
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })
```

---

**UPDATE**

Adding `_MyPartialView.cshtml`

```
@model MyMarkerObject

@{
    String title = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.GetTitle());
    String type = Model.GetDataElementType().ToString();
}
<div class="searchResult" style="margin-bottom:1em;">
    <div style="font-weight:200;">
        <span data-feather="GetTypeFeatherIcon(Model.GetDataElementType().Type)"></span> @Model.GetSourceName() > @Model.Source.LocationCountry
            @foreach (String loc in Model.Data.Locations)
            {
                loc.ToString();
            }
    </div>
    <div style="font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bolder;">@Html.ActionLink(title, "Details", type, new { id = Model.Id, sourceCollection = Model.GENSource.Collection, ta = "seairesultdetails" }, null)</div>
    <div>@Model.GetSourceURL()</div>
    <div>@Model.Collector.DateTimeUTC</div>
</div>
```

Comment: AFAIK it's impossibile. Javascript runs on the browser after `Html.Partial` that runs on the server.

Comment: What is the html generated by `_MyPartialView.cshtml`? You could simply this and improve performance by just including the data for your `InfoWindow` in the model

Comment: @StephenMuecke that is true that I could just include the data, since `_MyPartialView.cshtml` is moderately simple. However, it is used in multiple places throughout the project, and I'm trying not to copy/paste.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but if that is truly the best way to do this, then I will do it.

Comment: I cant help unless I know what the `_MyPartialView.cshtml` is :) And you only need to include it once in the view, inside a hidden element, and then `.clone()` it, add it to the DOM, and update its elements

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added!

Comment: @StephenMuecke And I should clarify that when I say that this partial view is used throughout the project, I mean in more than just this file. It sounds like the `.clone()` applies to only this file.

Comment: That makes no difference :) I'm about to eat so will take a look in 30 min or so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167155/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-emilia).

Comment: I've never chatted before.... Let me see if I can find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When view loaded all server side tags (Razor) will be loaded first then your javascript code will be executed , if you needed to call server side code from JS after your code loaded you need in this case to use asynchronous Ajax call.

This is example for your code

Controller

```
      [HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyPartialView( MyMarkerObject myMarkerObject )
{
        return PartialView("~/Views/Search/_MyPartialView.cshtml", myMarkerObject );
}
//Javascript
 $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("Search","MyPartialView")',
     type: 'POST',
     data: JSON.stringify(item),
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     error: function (xhr) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
     },
     success: function (result) {
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: result
        });
     },
     async: true,
     processData: false
  });
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, except that `_MyPartialView.cshtml` takes a `@model MyMarkerObject` instead of an `id`. Would I need to convert the current `MyMarkerObject` to a JSON string to pass it into `MyPartialView()` method, then change it back to the object, then pass it into `return PartialView()`? That seems strange. Is there a better way?

Comment: Check my edit I'm not tested this but i hope it be close to the answer

Comment: Alternative way maybe you pass List of MyMarkerObject to Partial View and then each result added to hidden field with unique id concatenated with index and take into consideration encodeding/decding html

Answer (score -2):

How about you pass the variable "i" as a query param and let your controller interpret it and use it as needed.

Something like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Search/_MyPartialView.cshtml?elementNo=" + i)
```

You can pass the model MyMarkerObject as well and then you can process it as needed.

Comment: That is not possible (`i` is a javascript variable which does not even exist when the the server side `@Html.Partial()` code is executed)

Comment: Can you help me a little more with the syntax please? I need the tick marks ` around the entire call like this `@Html....` because this returns a multi-line <div> that needs to be stringified. Using the syntax in the answer gives the error "The variable 'i' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Is this possible some other way? AJAX?